C++ std::string questionable usage
I am new to C++. In order to solve an online puzzle, I needed to extract numbers from strings and keep only the first and last number. For example 4nfhfbk56khfkvh => 456 => 46.
So I made the function given below.
int num_extr(const std::string &thisline){
 
     std::string stored_numbers = thisline;
     int i,k,result;
 
     k = 0;
 
     for(i=0; i<thisline.size(); i++){
 
         if(thisline[i] >= '0' && thisline[i] <= '9'){
             std::cout << "Number: " << thisline[i] << '\n';
             stored_numbers[k] = thisline[i];
             ++k;
         }
     }
     std::cout << "Stored_numbers: " << stored_numbers << '\n';
     std::cout << "Stored_numbers[0]: " << stored_numbers[0] << '\n';
     std::cout << "Stored_numbers[k-1]: " << stored_numbers[k-1] << '\n';

     if(k>0){
         result = ((int)stored_numbers[0] -48) * 10 + ((int)stored_numbers[k-1] -48);
     }
     else{
         result = ((int)stored_numbers[0] -48) * 10 + ((int)stored_numbers[0] -48);
     }
     return result;
 }


As you can see, I assign stored_numbers = thisline, in order to make the string stored_numbers
the same length as thisline (is this faster than using a function to find the length of thisline?). Then, I store the numbers I found on it, starting from [0].
This code works. This is an example of the output:
Initial string: trknlxnv43zxlrqjtwonect
Number: 4
Number: 3
Stored_numbers: 43knlxnv43zxlrqjtwonect
Stored_numbers[0]: 4
Stored_numbers[k-1]: 3
Extracted number: 43


But when I tried to not assign stored_numbers = thisline, so the code would be:
int num_extr(const std::string &thisline){
 
     std::string stored_numbers;
     int i,k,result;
 
     k = 0;
 
     for(i=0; i<thisline.size(); i++){
 
         if(thisline[i] >= '0' && thisline[i] <= '9'){
             std::cout << "Number: " << thisline[i] << '\n';
             stored_numbers[k] = thisline[i];
             ++k;
         }
     }
     std::cout << "Stored_numbers: " << stored_numbers << '\n';
     std::cout << "Stored_numbers[0]: " << stored_numbers[0] << '\n';
     std::cout << "Stored_numbers[k-1]: " << stored_numbers[k-1] << '\n';

     if(k>0){
         result = ((int)stored_numbers[0] -48) * 10 + ((int)stored_numbers[k-1] -48);
     }
     else{
         result = ((int)stored_numbers[0] -48) * 10 + ((int)stored_numbers[0] -48);
     }
     return result;
 }

Then the output is:
Initial string: trknlxnv43zxlrqjtwonect
Number: 4
Number: 3
Stored_numbers:
Stored_numbers[0]: 4
Stored_numbers[k-1]: 3
Extracted number: 43

So when I use stored_numbers as an array of (characters?) without the assignment, it seems like it is no longer one string, but it becomes a set of (pointers?) that cannot be presented as one string on cout...
Is this idea on the right direction? Could someone please explain this behavior in more depth?

I'll vote to close until you make this into a [mre].

But when I tried to not assign stored_numbers = thisline and you attempt to access characters of the empty string, this is undefined behavior, the program is not valid.

I removed lines from code snippets, put the program output inside code snippets and will make sure to not use too many tags next time. Thanks for the quick feedback.

@3CxEZiVlQ The program produced the correct answer for the puzzle both ways. My problem with it is that when I removed the assignment I expected to receive an error. I do not understand why I get no error.

Undefined behavior does not mean you get an error. Undefined behavior is undefined, worse case is that it may behave visually correctly. If you want the defined behavior then use .at(k) instead of [k].

@ΑλέξανδροςΠαππάς -- You are doing too much work.  To erase all characters that are not digits, use std::remove_if along with the erase function for std::string.  To get the first and last characters, use front() and back() to construct the new string.  To turn the new string into an integer, use std::stoi.  Basically 3 (or 4) functions.

So, you're supposed to find the first digit character in the string and the last digit character in the string? Search forward from the beginning of the string until you find a digit; that's the first one. Search backwrds from the end of the string until you find a digit; that's the last one.

@PaulMcKenzie Thanks for the suggestion, I am very skeptical of using functions for the time being, but I will check on those you used. Check Selbie's answer below, although it is more C, than C++, it is sublime.

I am very skeptical of using functions for the time being -- When you use the algorithm functions, 1) the code is guaranteed to work, given you use the correct functions and give the correct parameters to those functions, and 2) The code is self-documenting in that you see what functions are being called.  If you want to know what each line does, that is well-documented thus any C++ programmer that has experience knows exactly what that code does.  On the other hand, if I were to look at your code, it isn't clear what it does right away unless you told me and/or I run it to see what it does.

@ΑλέξανδροςΠαππάς Also, there is one flaw, actually, a flaw in the entire assignment.  What if the resulting number exceeds the maximum value of an int?

@PaulMcKenzie You are right, I did not think about the maximum value of int.. I get your point about self-documenting code by using functions, thanks!

A way simpler solution that takes advantage of only keeping the first and last digits found in the string.
Note: you don't need to hardcode "48" as the ascii (ordinal) value of '0'.  You can simply reference this value by the literal '0' as well.
int num_extr(const std::string &thisline){
    char first = '\0';   // null char, not literal '0'
    char last = '\0';    // null char, not literal '0'
    char* ptr = &first;

    for (char c : thisline) {
        if ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9')) {  // you can also use std::isdigit
           *ptr = c;
           ptr = &last;
        }
    }

    if (!first) {
       return 0;
    }

    if (!last) {
       return first - '0';
    }

    return 10*(first-'0') + (last-'0');
}

Now to answer your question. Let's look at this code snippet from your second code sample:
std::string stored_numbers;
int i,k,result;

k = 0;
 
for(i=0; i<thisline.size(); i++){
    if(thisline[i] >= '0' && thisline[i] <= '9'){
       std::cout << "Number: " << thisline[i] << '\n';
       stored_numbers[k] = thisline[i];
        ++k;
    }
}

The problem with the above is that stored_numbers does not have any pre-allocated length.  So when the code reaches this line:
stored_numbers[k] = thisline[i];
It's really not that much different from something like this:
int arr[3];   // valid indices are 0-2
arr[0] = 42;  // valid
arr[1] = 84;  // valid
arr[2] = 126; // valid
arr[3] = 168; // UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR

Or more closer to your example:
int arr[0];   // as odd as that looks, it's a valid array, but no index value is valid. Then length of the array is 0.
arr[0] = 42; // UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR

The moment you write at an index >= to the length of the array, you're in undefined behavior territory - with the usual effect being that you've tampered with memory belonging to another variable.  Same thing applies to a string since it's effectively a container for an array.  The conventional implementation of the string's [] operator is to simply return a pointer to the underlying array.
Now for the reason why your program still "happens to work" and print 43 at the end. Most likely, but not definitively, the string has both a length member as well as some pre-allocated buffers that you didn't actually overflow (yet).  So when cout << stored_numbers is executed, the string thought it's length is still zero since there were no valid append operations. So it streams no output. But when stored_numbers[0] is referenced, the string returns whatever it has in its buffer without checking the length member.  That's just a guess. "Undefined behavior" also means your code could turn you into a frog. But that's up to the compiler and runtime authors to decide.

I cannot vote yet, but thank you for your answer. Changing the pointer from first to second is a really cool idea. Also thanks for the other suggestions!

@Barmar I did not accept Selbie's answer as the solution, because although it's very helpful, it doesn't answer my main question about undefined behavior.

@ΑλέξανδροςΠαππάς - even if you don't find the an answer as to perfectly answering your question, you can still give it an upvote if you found it helpful in other ways.

@ΑλέξανδροςΠαππάς - and I answered your undefined behavior question anyway.

I need at least 15 reputation to upvote. Upvoting your answer was the first thing I tried, this is why in my first comment I said "I cannot vote yet". I will come back to upvote when I get 15 rep, your answer is very helpful. I accepted it as the solution as well. Thanks again!

There's no point in preallocateling the storage, especially by copying the original string, and especially when it is very likely that you will need much less space than the original string. It could be simpler like this:
int num_extr(const std::string &thisline){
 
     std::string stored_numbers;
 
     for(int i=0; i<thisline.size(); i++){
 
         if(thisline[i] >= '0' && thisline[i] <= '9'){
             std::cout << "Number: " << thisline[i] << '\n';
             stored_numbers += thisline[i];
         }
     }
     std::cout << "Stored_numbers: " << stored_numbers << '\n';
     std::cout << "Stored_numbers[0]: " << *stored_numbers.begin() << '\n';
     std::cout << "Stored_numbers[k-1]: " << *stored_numbers.rbegin() << '\n';

     ...

